# How can I make an Android app and a Website access the same Parse database?

Tags: parse-platform

My aim is to build an app to view the data and provide a web interface to modify the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same Application ID or Client Key (dont remember exactly atm) for Android Sdk and Rest Api (for PHP).
So you will use the same Database.